# Testing if a file descriptor is valid

Tags: bash, file-descriptors

I'd like to make a bash script output additional information to file descriptors (FDs) greater than or equal to 3, when they are open. To test whether an FD is open, I devised the following trick:

```
if (printf '' 1>&3) 2>&-; then
  # File descriptor 3 is open
else
  # File descriptor 3 is not open
fi
```

This is sufficient for my needs, but I'm curious as to whether there is a more idiomatic way of testing if an FD is valid. I'm especially interested about whether there exists a mapping of the `fcntl(1)` syscall to a shell command, which would allow the retrieval of FD flags (`O_WRONLY` and  `O_RDWR` to test whether the FD is writable, and `O_RDONLY` and  `O_RDWR` to test whether the FD is readable).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In `ksh` (both AT&T and pdksh variants) or `zsh`, you can do:

```
if print -nu3; then
  echo fd 3 is writeable
fi
```

They won't write anything on that fd, but still check if the fd is writable (using `fcntl(3, F_GETFL)`) and report an error otherwise:

```
$ ksh -c 'print -nu3' 3< /dev/null
ksh: print: -u: 3: fd not open for writing
```

(which you can redirect to `/dev/null`).

With `bash`, I think your only option is to check if a `dup()` succeeds like in your approach, though that won't guarantee that the fd is writable (or call an external utility (`zsh`/`perl`...) to do the `fcntl()`).

Note that in `bash` (like most shells), if you use `(...)` instead of `{...;}`, that will fork an extra process. You can use:

```
if { true >&3; } 2> /dev/null
```

instead to avoid the fork (except in the Bourne shell where redirecting compound commands always causes a subshell). Don't use `:` instead of `true` as that's a *special* builtin, so would cause the shell to exit when bash is in POSIX compliance mode.

You could however shorten it to:

```
if { >&3; } 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: @mikeserve, re: your edit, what's that with `<>`? The shell is not going to read from its stderr, why would you want to open it in read+write? What do you mean with *what happened to intrinsic?*?

Answer (score 6):

In the POSIX [`command`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/command.html) *Application Usage* description you'll find the following:

> There are some advantages to suppressing the special characteristics of special built-ins on occasion. For example:
>
> ```
> command exec > unwritable-file
> ```
>
> does not cause a non-interactive script to abort, so that the output status can be checked by the script.

This is why you can just do:

```
if    command >&3
then  echo 3 is open >&3
else  ! echo 3 is not open
fi    2<>/dev/null
```

Or...

```
{ command >&3
  printf %s\\n%.0d  string "0$(($??8:0))" >&"$(($??1:3))"
} 2<>/dev/null
```

Which will write *string* followed by a `\n`ewline either to stdout or 3 and still pass on a non-zero exit status when 3 is not open because the math done on `$?` winds up failing to convert the octal *08* to *%decimal* but truncates to nothing at all the octal *00*.

Or...

```
command exec >&3 || handle_it
```

But if you're using `ksh93`, you can just do:

```
fds
```

For a list of of open file descriptors. Add `-l` to see where they go.

Comment: `command exec >&3 || echo $?` does not echo the exit status, but `command >&3 || echo $?` does.

Comment: This doesn't actually work on bash -- gives '3: Bad file descriptor' if it is not open

Answer (score 3):

Your trick looks cute; but for an idiomatic way I wonder why you didn't use:

```
if ( exec 1>&3 ) 2>&-
```

Comment: This is, indeed, a cleaner way.

Comment: That creates a subshell though which is most shells means forking a process. That doesn't guarantee the fd is writeable. You can use `{ true >&3; } 2> /dev/null` to avoid the fork. Or `{ command exec >&3; } 2> /dev/null` if you want to redirect stdout to it.

Comment: @Stephane; The subshell trick that @Witiko invented was to not affect the file descriptors of the current environment when using a redirection to obtain a redirection. - Could you elaborate on the *"writable fd"* you mention?

Comment: `{ true >&3; } 2> /dev/null` will not affect the current environment either and won't fork (except in the Bourne shell). I mean that `(exec 1>&3) 2>&-` will return true for a fd open in read-only mode.

Comment: @Stephane; Sure, but why it's okay with `true` or `command exec` (as opposed to pure `exec`.

Comment: `exec` being a special builtin will exit the shell if it fails (for bash, only when in POSIX compliance mode). `command exec` prevents that. `true` is not a special builtin. Note that `exec` and `command exec` do affect the current environment (that's why I said _if you want to redirect stdout to it_).

Answer (score 3):

Open file descriptors can be found in `/proc/<pid>/fd`. To list, for example, the open file descriptors of the current shell you can issue `ls -l /proc/$$/fd` which should give you something like:

```
total 0
lrwx------ 1 testuser testuser 64 jun  1 09:11 0 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 testuser testuser 64 jun  1 09:11 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 testuser testuser 64 jun  1 09:11 2 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 testuser testuser 64 jun  1 09:39 255 -> /dev/pts/3
```

When you open a file using:

```
touch /tmp/myfile
exec 7</tmp/myfile
```

It should be listed by a new `ls -l /proc/$$/fd`:

```
lr-x------ 1 testuser testuser 64 jun  1 09:11 7 -> /tmp/myfile
```

If you close the file descriptor again using `exec 7>&-` it is also not listed in `/proc/$$/fd` anymore.

Comment: All this is quite specific to Linux.  FWIW.

Comment: Tested it on Linux as well as on Solaris (10 and 11). The difference is that you need to use `pfiles <pid>` to see which file descriptor is connected to which file while `ls -l` displays the connection on Linux.

Comment: I like the compactness of `[ -e /proc/$$/fd/3 ]`, but I prefer not to rely on procfs, as it is deprecated in FreeBSD and possibly other un*ces as well.

Comment: Brings me to the alternative of using `pfiles <pid>` or `lsof -p <pid>` to see which file descriptors are open.

Comment: `/proc` doesn't exist at all on OpenBSD.  On FreeBSD and NetBSD it has to be `mount`-ed explicitly, and `/proc/<PID>` don't have a subdirectory `fd`.

Comment: @Lambert: `pfiles` is not a universally available command and parsing information out of `lsof` (my take: ```[ -n "`lsof -p $$ | awk '{print $4}' | sed -n /3u$/p`" ]```) is arguably much less idiomatic than my original or Janis' approach. It would, however, be justified, if `lsof` enabled the retrieval of FD flags.

Comment: @Witiko, you mean `lsof -p $$ +f g`? BTW, `lsof` is also not universally available (the reason I use `pfiles` on Solaris). So it depends on the OS you are using to determine the best tool/method that fits your need.

Comment: That's useful. I'm going to wait if someone produces a more portable shell command that would provide access to the functionality of the POSIX-1 [`fcntl(1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/fcntl.h.html) syscall. If nobody does, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old - but anyway - why just do not use builtins?

```
for i in {0..5} ; do if [ -t $i ]; then echo "$i is a valid FD"; else echo "$i is INVALID FD"; fi; done
```

Output:

```
0 is a valid FD
1 is a valid FD
2 is a valid FD
3 is INVALID FD
4 is INVALID FD
5 is INVALID FD
```

So, to answer the question - would suggest:

```
if [ -t 3 ]; then
  # File descriptor 3 is open
else
  # File descriptor 3 is not open
fi
```

Comment: `-t` does not test if a file descriptor is valid, but if it's connected to a tty. Prepend a `echo yup |` to your script, and will say that `0 is INVALID FD`, while in fact it's very valid fd, a pipe.

Comment: @mosvy According to the POSIX standard, the `-t` test only returns `true` if the file descriptor is associated with a terminal. The reference is [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/test.html).

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- "associated with a terminal" is the same thing as "connected to a tty", but using different words.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux atleast, `[[ -e /dev/fd/${FD} ]]` will do, where FD is the bash-variable that stores the FD you want to test. The command succeeds when FD is open, fails otherwise.

Demo:

```bsh
exec 3<>/tmp/some-file
[[ -e /dev/fd/3 ]] && echo 'FD is open' || echo 'FD is closed'
exec 3<&- ; exec 3>&-
[[ -e /dev/fd/3 ]] && echo 'FD is open' || echo 'FD is closed'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are interested in a low forking solution so as to use it repeatdly, I would suggest this function:

```
checkfd() {
    exec 2>/dev/null
    if exec >&3 ; then
        exec 1>/dev/tty
        echo "fd3 OK"
    else
        echo "fd3 KO"
    fi
    exec 2>/dev/tty
}
```

And here is what it produces with a `zsh`:

```
$ checkfd            
fd3 KO
$ checkfd 3>/dev/null
fd3 OK
$
```

Comment: In most shells `exec >&3` will kill the shell when 3 is not open.

Comment: At least it is working on `zsh` and `bash`. Could you provide the shell on which the failing `exec` caused an `exit`?

Comment: Yeah. In `bash` do `set -o posix` and try again. In `zsh`... i think it's a matter of setting the env var `POSIX_BUILTINS` to a not-null value - but i forget offhand. In any case, `zsh` is not a shell which attempts to POSIX compliance, and so it is definitively non-standard. Both of those shells eschew compatibility for what *some* believe is convenience.

Comment: It is also working on plain Bourne shell.

Comment: In bash, with `set -o posix` a try is successful.

Comment: Which one is that? The POSIX [Consequences of Shell Errors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01) description is clear on how shell *special builtins* should behave in that context. Another way to make `bash` fail is to call it as `sh`. Also note that if you're doing your tests in an interactive shell - as opposed to a scripted shell - the behavior will differ.

Comment: Here's an example of how to call `bash` as a non-interactive shell from a prompt: `bash --posix <<""^Jexec 2>&3; echo hi` - where the `^J` represents the key-sequence `CTRL+V` then `CTRL+J` to quote the newline for the here-document. Afterwards you just press enter a few times and `bash` will print:  `bash: line 1: 3: Bad file descriptor` and *not* ***hi***. This is the same way it would behave if it were installed as `/bin/sh` and run as the system's default shell interpreter - such as from a `system()` call.