# Testing if a file descriptor is valid (for input)

Tags: shell, file-descriptors

In the question "[Testing if a file descriptor is valid](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206786)", a test is sought for testing whether a file descriptor is opened or not.

The answers all focus on testing whether the file descriptor is opened for *output*, but how may one test whether the file descriptor is opened for *input*?

This came up in a comment thread for an answer to another question, where the answer said, paraphrasing,

```
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    # read input from file "$1" (we're assuming it exists)
elif [ ! -t 0 ]; then
    # read input from standard input (from pipe or redirection)
else
    # no input given (we don't want to read from the terminal)
fi
```

The problem with `[ ! -t 0 ]` is that the `-t` test is true if the file descriptor is open *and* associated with a terminal.  If the test is false, then the descriptor is *either* closed, or not associated with a terminal (i.e. we're reading from a pipe or redirection). Testing with `[ ! -t 0 ]` is therefore not a guarantee that the file descriptor is even valid.

How to determine whether it's valid (so that `read` would not complain) or whether it's closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The check is easy to do in C with either `read(fd, 0, 0)` or `(fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) & O_WRONLY) == 0`. I wasn't able to trick any standard utility into doing just that, so here are some possible workarounds.

On linux, you can use `/proc/PID/fdinfo/FD`:

```
if [ ! -d "/proc/$$/fd/$fd" ] && grep -sq '^flags.*[02]$' "/proc/$$/fdinfo/$fd"; then
    echo "$fd" is valid for input
fi
```

On OpenBSD and NetBSD, you can use `/dev/fd/FD` and `dd` with a zero count:

```
if dd if=/dev/fd/3 count=0 3<&"$fd" 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "$fd" is valid for input
fi
```

On FreeBSD, only the first 3 fds are provided by default in `/dev/fd`; you should either mount `fdescfs(5)` on `/dev/fd` or:

```
if (dd if=/dev/fd/0 count=0 <&"$fd") 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "$fd" is valid for input
fi
```

Notes:

On some systems, `bash` does its emulation of `/dev/fd/FD`, and so `cat </dev/fd/7` may work completely different from `cat /dev/fd/7`. Same caveat applies to `gawk`.

A `read(2)` with length 0 (or an `open(2)` without `O_TRUNC` in its flags) will **not** update the access time or any other timestamps.

On linux, a `read(2)` will always fail on a directory, even if it was opened *without* the `O_DIRECTORY` flag. On other Unix systems, a directory may be read just like another file.

The [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) leaves unspecified whether `dd count=0` will copy no blocks or *all* blocks from the file: the former is the behaviour of GNU dd (`gdd`) and of the `dd` from *BSD.

Comment: It's the `open()` that fails on BSDs, so you migh as well do `if (true < /dev/fd/0) 2> /dev/null <&"$fd"` (assuming `fd` is not 2).

Comment: Thanks, but that would return true if the shell is `bash`, which does its own implementation of `/dev/fd`. Example: `bash -c '(true </dev/fd/0) <&7 && echo fine' 7>/dev/null`

Comment: Ah! Good catch.

Comment: One could implement this using [`ctypes.sh`](https://github.com/taviso/ctypes.sh) ;-).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for linux bash

```
if read -u $fd -n 0 -t 0 2>/dev/null
then
 ....
fi
```